# Redis: How to HMSET a dictionary from a Lua script?

Tags: python, redis, lua, nosql, lua-table

I am trying to pass a Python dict as an argument to a Lua script and `HMSET` it to a Redis key from the script.

I have two questions.

**How am I supposed to pass the dict from Python to Lua script and from the Lua script to Redis?**

Passing it to Lua seems straightforward, with a `json.dumps()`. However, how do I convert it back to a dict (or Lua table I guess?) in Lua (I can not use Lua's `require` inside Redis' `EVAL`).

Although I still don't know how to pass a real dict to Redis from Lua, I am still playing with `HMSET` inside the Lua script and trying to assign to the key a string.

**Why am I getting this error:**

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Error running script (call to f_2591f0a1987b36dd027b752af3591c92be845cd4):
@user_script:7: @user_script: 7: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script
```

provided that my Lua code uses the same number of args as my Python `HMSET`:

```
local key_name = KEYS[1]
redis.call('hmset', key_name, "some_val")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that a Pythonic dict is **not** the same as a Redis Hash: while a dict can store any type as value and supports nesting, hashes are only 1-level deep and store strings. So, if your dict is nested and/or contains non-string values the mapping is non-trivial.

Now, assuming that the dict is indeed non-nested.

> How am I supposed to pass the dict from Python to Lua script and from the Lua script to Redis?

As you're passing the JSONified representation, you can use [Redis' Lua `cjson` library](https://redis.io/commands/eval#cjson) to parse it into a Lua table, likeso:

```
local dict = cjson.decode(ARGS[1])
```

> Why am I getting this error:

The error is raised because you're calling `HMSET` (deprecated btw, replaced by `HSET`) without the field name argument. A correct way to do it (i.e. save the dict to a hash) would be something like the following:

```
local key_name = KEYS[1]
local dict = cjson.decode(ARGS[1])
for k, v in pairs(dict) do
  redis.call('HSET', key_name, k, v)
end
```

Or perhaps this slightly faster variant:

```
local key_name = KEYS[1]
local dict = cjson.decode(ARGS[1])
local payload = {}
for k, v in pairs(dict) do
  table.insert(payload, k)
  table.insert(payload, v)
end
redis.call('HSET', key_name, unpack(payload))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I actually specified the field name in HMSET, it is key_name. Any idea why it didn't work?

Comment: You need to specify the key, field and value for `HSET` - you only provided two of the three.

Comment: What is the difference between key and field? By using the same expression, e.g. ```redis.call('hmset', key_name, "some_val")``` I managed to set it without an error just by replacing "some_val" with a value I got from an existing Redis key. This is confusing to me as in this case I kept the number of arguments the same but the error was not present.

Comment: A key identifies a value in Redis. The value can be of different types - i.e. string, list, hash. In a hash value (under a single key) you can have one or more field-value pairs. I don't see how that 'hmset' could work without providing it with a key name and (at least) one field-value pair (making the total number of arguments to 'redis.call' command 4, including the 'hmset' command itself).

Comment: Oh I see. It seems the confusion came from the fact the Redis-Py I am using takes indeed two arguments: ```hmset(name, mapping)``` - the latter being a Python dict. And it seems what finally worked for me inside the Lua script: ```redis.call('HMSET', key_name, unpack(tmp_val))``` worked because ```unpack``` returns a list of unpacked values of the associative array. Thanks, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: why the need to copy from `dict` to `payload`, instead of just `unpack(dict)`?